# Is it possible to run a single Maestro flow against two different app ids?

Tags: maestro

We have an Android and an iOS app - independent codebases with independent app ids - and would like to run a single flow against each, or at the very least share subflows between flows for each app.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Common subflows won't work - they require an `appId` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in appID as an env variable:

```
appId: ${APP_ID}
---
- launchApp
```